# Map typescript parameter: Binding element 'columns' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

I have this code taken from a `JavaScript` post and I would like to use it in `TypeScript` but I get an error in `function ContactProps({ columns, data })`

The error is:

> Binding element 'columns' implicitly has an 'any' type.

and

> Binding element 'data ' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
function ContactProps({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({
      columns,
      data,
    });
```

Comment: You need to provide typings for the argument of `ContactProps`. Since the argument is an object (that you then destructure), you need to type annotate said object.

Comment: try `ContactProps({ columns, data }:any)`

Answer (score 0):

This one might solve your issue

```
 function ContactProps({ columns:any, data:any }) {
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({
      columns,
      data,
    });
```

or you can either remove the check for the "any" type in the declaration. In the **tsconfig.json** file, you could change the line

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```